# Decode function not working within for statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to replace some specific char from user input with a symbol (which is in UTF-8 format). The decode seems to be working but only for the **b** char when print. The char **a** remains the same.

In addition, when I remove char **b** from the **characters** dictionary, the char **a** will replace with the specified without any problem when print.

```py
characters = {
    'a': b'\xe1\x94\x91',
    'b': b'\xca\x96'
}

string = str()
    
for i, j in characters.items():
    string = arg.replace(i, j.decode('utf-8')) # arg is the input

print(string)
```

I am thinking the problem occurs within the **for** loop, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop you are replacing occurences in input string: `arg`. All previous replacements in `string` will be discarded. You have to reuse the string from previous iteration so the replacements accumulate:

```
string = arg
    
for i, j in characters.items():
    string = string.replace(i, j.decode('utf-8')) # arg is the input
```

Answer (score 1):

String is **immutable** in Python.

I.E., the value of a string can never be changed after it is initialized once.

Therefore, when performing string replace, the entire string must be re-initialized using

`my_string = my_string.replace`.

**Here is the working example:**

```
# File name: decode-demo.py

characters = {
    'a': b'\xe1\x94\x91',
    'b': b'\xca\x96'
}


arg = input("Enter a string: ")

output = arg
    
for i, j in characters.items():
    output = output.replace(i, j.decode('utf-8'))

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
> python decode-demo.py

Enter a string: abba

ᔑʖʖᔑ
```